# Can't restore backup: Failed with an unknown error

Tags: backup

I had backed up a directory of information on my old tower.  Stupidly, I did not check the restore before wiping the disk and reinstalling Ubuntu (18.04 current version)

I have a backup 32GB USB stick and the backup is in `/foo`

The backup utility,with the required library was instructed to restore from the backup location 32GB (name of the stick and the directory `/foo`

Which gets the message, "Failed with an unknown error." Then the diagnostic messages:

```
**Traceback (innermost last):
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1555, in <module>
    with_tempdir(main)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1541, in with_tempdir
    fn()
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1393, in main
    do_backup(action)
  File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1419, in do_backup
    action).set_values()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 710, in set_values
    self.get_backup_chains(partials + backend_filename_list)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 836, in get_backup_chains
    add_to_sets(f)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 824, in add_to_sets
    if set.add_filename(filename):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/collections.py", line 105, in add_filename
    (self.volume_name_dict, filename)
 AssertionError: ({1: 'duplicity-inc.20190319T194123Z.to.20190329T203413Z.vol1.difftar.gz'}, 'duplicity-inc.20190319T194123Z.to.20190329T203413Z.vol1.difftar')**
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  TIA